# Trying to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData from Nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have migrated my project into Visual Studio 2013 from 2010.  I am trying to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData to fix some erors I am getting.  When I try install from the Nuget console I get this error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData 3.2.2'. **You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework.** For more information,
>   contact the package author.
>       At line:1 char:16
>       + Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You mean I need to switch to .net 4.5?

Comment: Or install an older version of the nuget package that still targets 4.0 (not always possible, I didn't check for this particular package if it has a 4.0 incarnation)